# How to clean up akka-http websocket resources following disconnection and then retry?

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http

The code below successfully establishes a websocket connection.

The websockets server (also akk-http) deliberately closes the connection using [Andrew's suggested answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40962834/2074859).

The `SinkActor` below receives a message of type `akka.actor.Status.Failure` so I know that the flow of messages from Server to Client has been disrupted.

My question is ... How should my client reestablish the websocket connection?  Has `source.via(webSocketFlow).to(sink).run()` completed?

What is best practice for cleaning up the resources and retrying the websocket connection?

```
class ConnectionAdminActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  implicit val system: ActorSystem = context.system
  implicit val flowMaterializer    = ActorMaterializer()

  private val sinkActor = context.system.actorOf(Props[SinkActor], name = "SinkActor")

  private val sink = Sink.actorRefWithAck[Message](sinkActor, StartupWithActor(self.path), Ack, Complete)

  private val source = Source.actorRef[TextMessage](10, OverflowStrategy.dropHead).mapMaterializedValue {
    ref => {
      self ! StartupWithActor(ref.path)
      ref
    }
  }

  private val webSocketFlow: Flow[Message, Message, Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse]] =
Http().webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest("ws://localhost:8080"))

  source
    .via(webSocketFlow)
    .to(sink)
    .run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `recoverWithRetries` combinator (docs [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#recoverWithRetries)).

This allows you to provide an alternative `Source` your pipeline will switch to, in case the upstream has failed. In the most simple case, you can just re-use the same `Source`, which should issue a new connection.

```
val wsSource = source via webSocketFlow

wsSource
  .recoverWithRetries(attempts = -1, {case e: Throwable => wsSource})
  .to(sink)
```

Note that

- the `attempts = -1` will retry to reconnect indefinetely
- the partial function allows for more granular control over which exception can trigger a reconnect

Comment: Thanks Stefano.  It does answer my question (at least the part about "retrying").  A detail that I omitted, was that I wanted to retry with slightly different behavior.  I have a solution for that now.